# can i limit a string using binding?

Tags: wpf, string, binding, format, limit

I have this binding

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Client.Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Now I wanted to limit the size of the string binding
Example:if Client.Name had 50 characters, I would like to show only 25 characters

how can I limit this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this using a value converter:

Something like this (this may need tweaking as I am away from my dev machine so this is from memory).

```
public class StringLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (string)value.SubString(0, this.Length);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An alternative solution is to just return the string of the required length straight from the viewModel e.g. if you have a client with a name of 30 characters, your viewModel could just return the first 25 characters:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _name.SubString(0, 25);
            // Notify property changed....
        }
    }
}
```